# Error in compilation saying that The resource name must start with a letter

Tags: android, android-studio, merge, android-gradle-plugin

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> C:\Users\vipin\Desktop\working\chatbot-watson-android\app\src\main\res\values\config.xml: Error: The resource name must start with a letter.
```

I am not able to find the bug. My gradle version is 3.0.1. 
My `config.xml` file is below.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!--suppress ALL -->    
    <resources>
     <!-- Watson Conversation Service Credentials --> 
    <string name="02b40d22-cf18-49f6-a209-29167f5e51b2"></string> 
    <string name="0ea4b080-6bdd-48d8-b327-c8d4e4939c"></string> 
    <string name="oJFe0L4Svsbk"></string>  

    <!--Watson Speech-To-Text Service Credentials--> 
    <string name="STT_username"></string> 
    <string name="STT_password"></string>  

    <!--Watson Text-To-Speech Service Credentials--> 
    <string name="TTS_username">9a50095e-b6a7-4f05-80b0-3c5192f07e38</string>  
    <string name="TTS_password"></string>

    <!--Bluemix Mobile Analytics--> 
    <string name="mobileanalytics_apikey">5bc78043-759d-4e52-9355-861b406bdaef</string>
</resources>
```

---

Please help!

Comment: make sure that all your resource and drawable file are named properly there is some file which is not starting with letter so you are getting this error

Comment: the two first "watson conversation service credentials" have a name starting with a digit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

replace with below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Watson Conversation Service Credentials -->     
    <string name="workspace_id">02b40d22-cf18-49f6-a209-29167f5e51b2</string>     
    <string name="conversation_username">0ea4b080-6bdd-48d8-b327-c8d4e4939c</string>     
    <string name="conversation_password">oJFe0L4Svsbk</string>          
<!--Watson Speech-To-Text Service Credentials-->     
    <string name="STT_username"></string>     
    <string name="STT_password"></string>          

    <!--Watson Text-To-Speech Service Credentials-->     
    <string name="TTS_username">9a50095e-b6a7-4f05-80b0-3c5192f07e38</string>          
    <string name="TTS_password"></string>

    <!--Bluemix Mobile Analytics-->     
    <string name="mobileanalytics_apikey">5bc78043-759d-4e52-9355-861b406bdaef</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It helped.

Answer (score 0):

You must change the names of resources mentioned to convenient ones.
For example instead of writing :

```
<string name="02b40d22-cf18-49f6-a209-29167f5e51b2"></string>
```

change it to :

```
<string name="watson_credential_1">02b40d22-cf18-49f6-a209-29167f5e51b2</string>
```

You must change names of resources to start with a letter, 
Thats what it means by **The resource name must start with a letter.**